# Fixing NAs represented by 9s (ex: 99, 999, 9999) matching column width in data.table (or in fread)

Tags: r, data.table, na, fread

It is common for data in text files to have variable-length sequences of 9s representing NAs. That is, the number of 9s that represent the NA depends on the number of characters in each variable. For instance:

- a 2 digit state code will have 99 representing NAs
- a 3 digit variable will have 999 representing NAs. Note that in this case 99 could be a legal (non-NA) value.

What is the best way to clean these values?

Note that, in `fread`, `na.values=c('99','999')` is not an ideal option because it will destroy the legal 99 values in 3 digit variables.

Let's say I have `data.table` `d`, and two sets of numeric columns

```
cols_2digit <- c('a','b')
cols_3digit <- c('c','d')
```

How can I replace sequences of 9s by NAs in all columns of each set at once? The number of sets is limited, so one command per set is fine.

OBS: these variable-length NA codes are reminiscent of fixed-width files (fwf), even if modern files are provided in csv (which could take a standard "999999" value for NA across columns).

Comment: When you say that legal value in column width, how do you determine column width if the values are `99, 9999, 42, 64, 426`

Comment: hum, good question. I think the width comes from analyst observing the modal column length, how often it occurs and knowledge of the possible values for a column (in a state code example)

Comment: I added a soluiton to do this automatically.  Not tested.  hopefully, it works

Comment: In the sequence above, I suppose at least 3 digits would be possible, which would make 99 legal. But the fact that 9999 has more digits then all other values is a bit weird if this was coming from a fwf (or reminiscent of it)

Comment: ok, in the third solution, a `Mode` is calculated on the `nchar` for each column and then we get the elements that are only 9, check if that width is same as the  column width from Mode and assign it to NA

Comment: Tks a lot. Upon further thinking, the mode is not good. You could be representing groups by 1, 2, 3... and then the number of groups overflows to 2 digits for the last group. Group 10. In that case, group 10 will represent only around 10% of the observations. But it is still legal. So perhaps max is better than mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `set` by looping over the columns specified in 'cols_2digit', or 'cols_3digit' and change the values in the columns in place

```
for(j in cols_2digit) set(d, i = which(d[[j]] == '99'), j = j, value = NA_character_)
for(j in cols_3digit) set(d, i = which(d[[j]] == '999'), j = j, value = NA_character_)
```

---

Or another option is `Map`

```
d[, c(cols_2digit, col2_3digit) := 
     Map(function(dat, y) lapply(dat, function(x) 
         fifelse(x, x == y, NA_character_)), list(.SD[, ..cols_2digit],
                             .SD[, ..cols_3digit]), list('99', '999')) ]
```

---

Also, instead of doing this on different sets, another option is to find the column width based on the max frequency

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
   }

d[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {
                # get the most frequent column width
                colwidth <-  Mode(nchar(x))
                # if it is max 
                # colwidth <- max(nchar(x))
                # get the elements that are only 9 from start (`^`) to end (`$`)
                i1 <- grepl('^9+$', x) 
                # do the assignment based on the index
                x[i1][nchar(x[i1]) == colwidth] <- NA_character_
                x
              })]
```

Comment: if data is really big then the following approach could be helpful to speed it up: `setindexv(d, as.list(c(cols_2digit,cols_3digit))); for (j in cols_2digit) set(d, i=eval(substitute(d[.j=='99', which=TRUE], env=list(.j=as.name(j)))), j=j, value=NA_character_)`. API will be simpler after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304